# Points to be considered for Salesforce Instance movement from NA to EU

Tags: migration, instance

I am working for a project that requires Salesforce data center to be migrated (moved) from NA to EU due to security reasons. This org migration from server is obviously going to be done by Salesforce itself. But I'm not sure on what will happen to the data created for standard and custom objects. Will those be migrated to as a part of Salesforce doing the org migration or is this something that need to be carried out by doing ETL work.

Although I was checking few articles over the internet but didn't get a clear picture about it. Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Salesforce migrated our org from ap1 to ap4 and it all went very smoothly. Everything, data/configuration/code, was moved over for us without requiring any work on our end. If you haven't seen it yet, [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Instance-Refresh-Maintenance-FAQ&language=en_US&eid=ss-tc) is worth checking out.

Comment: @martin: thanks for the infomation. Also could you please let me know if saleasforce charges extra amount for data migration or is it inlcluded as a whole in the total package?

Comment: Actually our situation was a bit different since it was salesforce that decided to move us instead of us asking to move, so I can't really speak to how they would charge for the service.

Comment: Question: I assume that the record id's have changed? Or do they stayed the same
I just wondering in regards to any integration like eloqua mapping contact ids with salesforce record ids

Comment: @Moggy The ids of existing record will stay the same, and new records are given ids based on the pod identifier of the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

[How to Prepare for an Org Migration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334938&type=1), presumably created long after this question existed, serves to cover the various consideration/questions. Below is a list of things to consider preparing to do or checking on:

> - Enabling My Domain (NOTE: My Domain is required for customers that have requested the org migration.), and if you have any hard-coded references (for example, na1.salesforce.com) make sure that you update them to relative URLs (for example, login.salesforce.com or your My Domain subdomain) prior to the org migration.
> - Removing Hard-Coded References. For more information, see the article, [Updating Hard-Coded References](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&id=Updating-Hard-Coded-References-FAQ).
> - If you or your company has set up your corporate network settings or email security filters to restrict access to only certain IP ranges, please ensure that you update the your lists to include our newest ranges. More information on IP ranges can be found in the article, [Salesforce IP Addresses to Allow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1&language=en_US).
> - Prepare to refresh integrations if you are experiencing integration issues following the maintenance.
> - Prepare to refresh your DNS cache if you continue to see a “Maintenance in Progress” alert on your login page following the maintenance window.
> - If you locally cache certificates, join the [Certificate Changes](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oAF) group in the Trailblazer Community to get the latest certificates.

For the specific question

> But I'm not sure on what will happen to the data created for standard
> and custom objects. Will those be migrated to as a part of Salesforce
> doing the org migration or is this something that need to be carried
> out by doing ETL work.

Existing records will be migrated for you and their IDs will not change.

---

Some other considerations for certain features

- [Event Bus](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334938&type=1#:%7E:text=nature%20of%20our-,Event%20Bus,-%2C%20we%20are%20not)

> certain migrations require relocating your organization to another
> data center or to a different hardware stack. During these operations,
> we are physically moving your data and running the software which
> serves your applications onto different hardware. Due to the
> distributed, asynchronous nature of our Event Bus, we are not able to
> migrate all events that were published prior to the org migration

- [Live Agent](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=Live-Agent-server-endpoint-URL-has-changed-and-now-Live-Agent-Chat-is-no-longer-working&type=1&language=en_US) - depending on if you have a custom/3rd-party applications, you'll want to handle the change in URL.
- Bots - Following a migration, you'll need to ensure the Einstein bots preference is toggled on and re-associate any bots to the channels for which they were deployed. Utterance data will be moved over, but NLP models in their bots will need to be re-trained before being usable in the bot. Bot session event log data and the bot session object data is not moved during the org migration process.
- Event Monitoring - not all event log data will be migrated, but most will.

> Any log data not processed before the org migration will not be
> available on the new instance. When the migration starts, data from
> that day until the day the migration completes, won't be added to the
> org in its new location. This is because Event Monitoring relies on
> log data and a nightly batch process to populate monitoring events.

- Hold off on Sandbox Refreshes

> Full sandbox refresh should not be
> requested up to two weeks prior to the org migration, and Developer or
> Developer Pro copies should not be initiated one week prior to the
> migration.

- Email Logs from your former data center cannot be extracted after the org migration. You can request your email logs prior to the maintenance which will ensure they're stored in the database and then migrated along with your other data.